# Why in nuxtjs application with tailwindcss I got error @apply` cannot be used with .xl\:w-8\/12?

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

i have nuxtjs application with tailwindcss selected during installation
and trying to add custom class from laravel 8/tailwindcss 2 application I got error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                                                            friendly-errors 08:04:33


 ERROR  in ./assets/css/style.css                                                                                                                                                                                  friendly-errors 08:04:33

Syntax Error: SyntaxError                                                                                                                                                                                          friendly-errors 08:04:33

(42:9) `@apply` cannot be used with .xl\:w-8\/12 because .xl\:w-8\/12 is nested inside of an at-rule (@media).

  40 |     /*profile_page_container*/
  41 |     .profile_page_container_wrapper {
> 42 |         @apply flex-1 app_main_color border-2 border-green-500 rounded-lg w-full xl:w-8/12 m-0 p-1;
     |         ^
  43 |     }
  44 | 


                                                                                                                                                                                                                   friendly-errors 08:04:33
 @ ./assets/css/style.css 4:14-163 15:3-20:5 16:22-171
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/eventsource-polyfill/dist/browserify-eventsource.js (webpack)-hot-middleware/client.js?reload=true&timeout=30000&ansiColors=&overlayStyles=&path=%2F__webpack_hmr%2Fclient&name=client ./.nuxt/client.js
```

When in `assets/css/style.css` I added the following lines :

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
  .d1 {
    @apply border-2 border-red-600;
  }

  h3 {
    @apply text-xl font-bold app_main_color;
    padding: 4px;
  }

  h4 {
    @apply text-lg font-bold app_main_color;
    padding: 3px;
  }

  /* error at line below shows at xl\:w-8 */
  .profile_page_container_wrapper {
    @apply flex-1 app_main_color border-2 border-green-500 rounded-lg w-full xl:w-8/12 m-0 p-1;
  }
}
```

In `nuxt.config.js` I have the following:

```js
buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss'],
css: [
  {
    src: '~assets/css/style.css',
    lang: 'css'
  }
],
```

I see that my custom classes are applied in my app ok.
How that could be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

@apply cannot be used with responsive classes; You can use @screen directive to reach  the desired outcome:

```
@screen xl {
    .profile_page_container_wrapper {
        @apply w-8/12;
    }
}
```

For more information you can see the following links:

[@apply cannot be used with responsive classes?](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/discuss/issues/91)

[Tailwind CSS @apply directive](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#apply)